# Python Multiple Values For One Key in a defaultdict(dict)

Tags: python, dictionary, input, graph, collections

I'm trying to create a directed graph with optional edge weights using a defaultdict. Here is my program:

```
import sys
import collections
myGraphLines = sys.stdin.readlines()
myGraphLines = [i.split() for i in myGraphLines]
myDefaultDict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
print(myDefaultDict)
myDefaultDict = {e[0] : {e[1] : e[2] if len(e) == 3 else True} for e in myGraphLines}
print(myDefaultDict)
```

When I run:

```
SanFrancisco Houston 1000
Austin           Houston 500
NYC   LA  3000
LA SanFrancisco
LA Ames 300
LA Detroit 200
^D
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {})
{'NYC': {'LA': '3000'}, 'LA': {'Detroit': '200'}, 'SanFrancisco': {'Houston': '1000'}, 'Austin': {'Houston': '500'}}
```

But if I am creating a directed graph, I need to have `'LA'` pointing to `'SanFrancisco', 'Ames',` and `'Detroit'` But it is only pointing to Detroit.

I feel like I'm not using the defaultdict at all, but I can't find anywhere that talks about how to fill it up the way I want to. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `myDefaultDict = {e[0] : {e[1] : e[2] if len(e) == 3 else True} for e in myGraphLines}` ignores and discards the defaultdict you constructed earlier.

Comment: Yeah I felt like that was it haha, where can I find on how to use the defaultdict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a defaultdict, you pretty much always have to populate it with an explicit loop:

```
myDefaultDict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for e in myGraphLines:
    myDefaultDict[e[0]][e[1]] = e[2] if len(e) == 3 else True
```

It's the kind of thing where it initially feels like there should be some spiffy way to use some sort of dict comprehension or something. Even when you can use a comprehension, though, it's usually either quadratic time or a case where you don't really need a defaultdict at all.